# Sleeping Tumah Transfers

Tags: sleep, netilat-yadayim-washing

If someone wakes up and touches another object before washing his/her hands, does that object get some level of tumah as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple answer no.

Complex answer, there is a mahloket as to exactly why we wash our hands in the morning.  Some hold that is is because we have touched an unclean part of the body, some hold that is is because of a ruah ra that rests upon a person while they are asleep, some hold that is not a ruah ra but rather klipot or hiztoniut that rest upon a person while they are asleep, and thus must be driven off before one can start to pray.  However none of those things is listed by Hazal as a form of tumah that is capable of being passed on, to an additional object.

Comment: I think the Rambam is quoted as saying we wash when waking up to a day of service of Hashem, just as kohanim wash when starting their Temple service.  Again, wouldn't transmit tumah.

Comment: There are 2 reasons to wash hands in the morning.  The first  reason is for tefilla.  This is the washing that we say al netilas yadayim on.  There is a machlokes, usually brought between the Rosh and the Rashba, as to why.  The Rosh requires cleanliness mornibefore davening.  The assumption is that you have touched unclean areas while asleep.  The Rashba requires kedusha for your "new being" similar to kohanim (also because of tefilla.  This netila requires only one rinse (and can be done,if there's no water, with anything that cleans.  Con't below.

Comment: The second reason is for fear that a ruach ra'a will damage us.  For this:  Only water, 3x alternating and no bracha.  (Whether you need a keli for any of this is another discussion.)

Comment: I assume what mekubal means is that even though the ruaach r'aa can be mazik, the ruach itself doesn't transfer.

Comment: However, I have heard that one should be careful not to touch food, and if one does, there can be problems... According to your answer, why should that be so?

Comment: And indeed, Rashi (Yoma 77b, ד"ה מדיחה) points out that this "ruach ra'ah" can be transferred to food. Could be that it's symbolic of the rules for real tum'ah, where one's hands (which are שניות Rabbinically) can render only foods and liquids impure.

Comment: I've also heard that one should not touch the body's orifices before washing (eyes, mouth, etc.) because of the Ruach Ra'ah.  But I've wondered if Ruach Ra'ah might be euphemism (or generic term) for just about anything that was unknown that could cause illness (eg., bacteria that can develop if one has not washed one's hands thoroughly after using the bathroom prior to sleeping and then leting the bacteria then fester overnight). Would the idea of washing with a Keli be because rinsing in water that sat overnight potentially has the same festering potential, whereas moving water can wash ...

Comment: ...away dirt and bacteria? Might this explain why one can use anything that cleans (cloth, wood, etc. - I've even heard sand is acceptable - but that water is preferred)? I wash 3x alternating on each hand, btw.

Comment: @Shalom I think that is from the Avuderham.